# How to pass array in where condition of Query with one "Not Equal" Condition

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am working on Laravel 5.2. I faced a problem for sending an array to model function with one on my value is Not Equal.

I check this way is working:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
->where([ ['status','1'], ['subscribed','!=','1'], ])
->get();
```

But in my case, i am working in a reusable function:

```
$whereData = array('name'=>'test' , 'id !=' => '5');
$users = DB::table('users')->where($whereData)->get();
```

Here Not Equal to condition not working and provides error. What is correct syntax for using this reusable function with whereData array consists of multiple operators like "!= , <> , etc ...".

Comment: So, You want to get the results from `users` table where `status=1` or `subscribed!=1`?

Comment: No please ready carefully. I want reusable function works with "$whereData = array('name'=>'test' , 'id !=' => '5');". Which goes to model function and gives records name is test and id is not equal to 5. But  'id !=' => '5' is not working for laravel.

Comment: Try `<>` instead of `!=`

Comment: It is also not working. Is laravel provides this way working or not.

Comment: I want to pass where data in form of array. Therefore i am using "$whereData = array('name'=>'test' , 'id !=' => '5');" this but it is not working for me.

Comment: In this [url](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#where-clauses), check the following code `$users = DB::table('users')->where([
    ['status','1'],
    ['subscribed','<>','1'],
])->get();`

Comment: try `$whereData = [ ['name','test'], ['id','!=','5'], ];`

Comment: @Gunaseelan i already check this but i want to pass as parameter WHERE condtion in to laravel model function. So how to pass if one of value consists of "!=" operator.

Comment: @Maantje already try this way but the query not working.

Comment: @steven what is the error you get?

Comment: @Gunaseelan 500 internal server error.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you the following way.

Only send the data without where condition.

Therefore,

```
$whereData = array('name'=>$username , 'statusid' => $userid);

$users = DB::table('users')->where('status', '=', $whereData['name'])->orWhere('subscribed', '<>', $whereData['statusid'])->get();
```

or as you mentioned, replace `where` with `whereColumn`

Thus the code will be,

```
$whereData = array( array('name','test') , array( 'id','<>','5'));
$users = DB::table('users')->whereColumn($whereData)->get();
```

Comment: @steven check out the solution.